# pass a get-Azureaduser property to set-Azureaduser as a string

Tags: powershell, office365

I need to update the AzureADuser property companyname with the Physicaldeliveryofficename value. When I use:
`Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId TEst_USer@foo.com | Set-AzureADUser -userprincipalname $_.userpricipalname -CompanyName $_.Physicaldeliveryofficename`

the companyname property is not updated. I think I'm missing the formatting for the `$_.propertyname` value to convert to a string for the `-companyname` property.

Comment: you're using `$_.Physicaldeliveryofficename` as if you were using `ForEach-Object`. Try with `... | ForEach-Object { Set-AzureAd.... }`

Comment: Where are you getting the new values for `UserPrincipalName` and `Physicaldeliveryofficename` from? This looks like you are 'updating' a user with properties he/she already had...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `ForEach-Object` if you want to reference `$_.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName` from pipeline. This example should add clarity to your code:

```
$azUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId TEst_USer@foo.com
Set-AzureADUser $azUser -CompanyName $azUser.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
```

Alternatively, if you want to do it on one pipeline, using `-PipelineVariable` *may work*:

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId TEst_USer@foo.com -PipelineVariable azUser |
Set-AzureADUser -CompanyName $azUser.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
```

Comment: Thanks the first example worked like a charm.

Comment: @MWolfe60 happy to help. please, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer if it answered your question.